# OkHttp "java.net.ProtocolException: Unexpected status line: nullHTTP/1.1 200 OK" after a "204 NO-CONTENT" response using same connection

Tags: java, http, okhttp

I need to do a sequence of calls using same connection (okhttpclient fits my needs) and one of them returns a 204 status code (no body), but after "204 call" with success:

```
java.net.ProtocolException: Unexpected status line: nullHTTP/1.1 200 OK
at okhttp3.internal.http.StatusLine.parse(StatusLine.java:69)
at okhttp3.internal.http.Http1xStream.readResponse(Http1xStream.java:184)
at okhttp3.internal.http.Http1xStream.readResponseHeaders(Http1xStream.java:125)
at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine.readNetworkResponse(HttpEngine.java:775)
at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine.access$200(HttpEngine.java:86)
at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine$NetworkInterceptorChain.proceed(HttpEngine.java:760)
at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:613)
at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponse(RealCall.java:244)
at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:201)
at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:163)
at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:57)
at it.test.Main.main(Main.java:48)
```

Using request header "Connection: close" (so not reusing connection) problem doesn't occur.

This is a working main reporting the problem. It uses okHttp v3.3.0 and okio v1.8.0

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
try {
    String url200 = "http://www.cmsservice.provahosting.it/index.php?option=com_cmsmanager&key=ca25131a2f77fb2b80d82e63412fdc13&debug=1&cmd=status";
    String url204 = "http://www.cmsservice.provahosting.it/index.php?option=com_cmsmanager&key=ca25131a2f77fb2b80d82e63412fdc13&debug=1&cmd=getUpdates";

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();

    //First request
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url200)/*.addHeader("Connection", "close")*/
            .build();

    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    System.out.println(response.code()+">>>>" + response.body().string().getBytes().length + "<<<<");
    response.body().close();

    //Second request
    Request request2 = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url204)/*.addHeader("Connection", "close")*/
            .build();
    response = client.newCall(request2).execute();
    System.out.println(response.code()+">>>>" + response.body().string().getBytes().length + "<<<<");
    response.body().close();

    //Third request
    Request request3 = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url200)/*.addHeader("Connection", "close")*/
            .build();
    response = client.newCall(request3).execute();
    System.out.println(response.code()+">>>>" + response.body().string().getBytes().length + "<<<<");
    response.body().close();

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Could someone help me understanding what I'm missing or if it is a bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like your webserver is claiming the prior response has no body, but then writing a four character body “null”. Report the problem to the webserver’s maintainers and they should fix it.

Comment: Tnx for your reply. but running code above response body of 204 request is empty (0 bytes) so I don't understand where "null" come from... Does okhttp client give a 0 length body by default for a 204? Or it really looks at stream?

Comment: Using a packet analyzer (wireshark) I can see the "null" ... so you are right :). Tnx again